# Загрузка бинарного файла на устройство

Tags: java, загрузка

Задача: скачать файл из БД формата mp4 как бинарный файл. 
Проблема: файл скачивается, но всегда в каком-то "урезанном формате". Если скачиваю с одной и той же БД, все файлы одного размера (109 КБ), хотя на деле размер другой. При скачивании по ссылке, размер отличается (при скачивании с облака майл, размер 40,43), но видео опять же не открывается. 
В дальнейшем будет необходимо этот файл открыть в videoView. 
В чем проблема?

```
        void loadBinary(String url, String name) {
    try {
        VidActivity.videoPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/" + name;
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            File file = new File(VidActivity.videoPath); //Создаем файловую переменную
            if (!file.exists()) { //Если не существует
                result = file.createNewFile();  //создаем
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = false;
        }
        int b = 0;

        try {


            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                b = is.read();
                out.write(b);
            }
            out.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {  // Прочитали один байт и посмотрели на результат
  b = is.read();  // Прочитали еще один байт
  out.write(b);  // последний прочитанный байт записали
}
```

Должно быть

```
while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {  // Прочитали один байт и посмотрели на результат
  out.write(b);  // если байт был прочитан, то записали его
}
```

Еще лучше читать не по одному байту, а блоками

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int cnt;
while ((cnt = is.read(buf)) != -1) {  // Прочитали все байты в буфер и посмотрели на результат
  out.write(buf, 0, cnt);  // если что-то прочитали, то записали столько байт, сколько прочитали
}
```

Comment: проблема не решена, все осталось по-прежнему, размер загружаемых файлов такой же.